# find q-table for discrete action space

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning, openai-gym

I am trying to use q-learning for a discrete observation space that is represented by:

- buffer: list of 200 integer values in [0,10]
- discard_counter: list of 200 integer values in [0, 4]
- capacity: list of 30integer values in [-1,10]

I think buffer and discard counter can be combined into one 2D array as for every buffer entry there is a value and a discard counter.

So in order to represent all states I use the following method:

```
    def obs_to_state(self):
        #maps obs to int value, because i am unable to think in 6 dimensions
        obs = self.env.get_obs()
        arr1 = np.zeros((200, 11, 5)) # array representing buffer and discard_counter
        for i in range(len(obs['buffer'])):
            dc = obs['discard_counter'][i]
            val = obs['buffer'][i]
            arr1[i, val, dc] = 1
        arr1 = list(arr1.flatten())
        arr2 = np.zeros((30, 12))   # capacity array
        for i, v in enumerate(obs['capacity']):
            arr2[i, v] = 1
        arr2 = list(arr2.flatten())
        return arr1 + arr2
```

this method gives me a list of length 200*11*5*30*12=11360. However each of these values can be either 0 or 1 (and most combinations are possible states that can be reached). This results in overall 2**11360 possible states which is a number that definitely is too big for using q-learning with a q-table. In order to create the q-table I have to create an array of size 11360*2 (there are only 2 actions). Am I missing something or is q-learning not a good idea for this task?

Here is the description of the task and the code I have so far:

A startup wants to run multiple workflows simultaneously. Given the low budget of the
company, only one local resource (LR) and some EC2 instances are available to run
all the workflow tasks. The scheduler that coordinates the execution wants to learn
when a particular task should be executed locally or offloaded to the cloud.
Consider the following restrictions:
Tasks durations are discrete values between 1 and 10 time slots.
LR capacity is 30 time slots. If capacity is not enough, tasks will be discarded.
Processing rate of LR is 2 time slots per Q-learning iteration.
Offloading to cloud costs 4 time slots.
An unlimited buffer can be used to queue tasks until LR is available. Buffered tasks
are discarded after 4 time slots.
The task arrival frequency is totally up to you.

- Create a custom Gym environment out of your MDP model.
- Implement Q-learning and obtain the optimal policy that maximize the
  cumulative reward.

Code:
The Agent class is work in progress and num_states needs to be 2**11360 but my Laptop cannot do this.

````
import gym
from gym import spaces
from gym.envs.registration import register
import random
from gym.utils.env_checker import check_env
import numpy as np
from itertools import product

# source: https://www.gymlibrary.dev/content/environment_creation/
# source: https://www.gymlibrary.dev/content/basic_usage/

class Env(gym.Env):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.N = 200
        self.step_cnt = 0
        self.schedule_time = 2
        self.reward = 0

        self.observation_space = spaces.Dict({
            "capacity": spaces.Box(low = 0, high = 10, shape=(30,), dtype=int),
            "buffer": spaces.Box(low = 0, high = 10, shape=(self.N,), dtype=int),
            "discard_counter": spaces.Box(low = 1, high = self.schedule_time, shape=(self.N,), dtype=int)
        })
        # execute (1) or offload (2)
        self.action_space = spaces.Discrete(2)

    def get_obs(self):
        return({
            "capacity": self.capacity,
            "buffer": self.buffer,
            "discard_counter": self.discard_counter
        })
    
    def create_tasks(self):
        result = []
        while self.N > 0:
            # Generate a random self.N between 1 and 10 (inclusive)
            value = random.randint(1, 10)
            value = min(value, self.N)
            result.append(value)
            self.N -= value
        return result

    def reset(self, seed = None, options = None):
        #super.reset(seed = seed) super has no reset method...
        self.capacity = [0 for x in range(30)]
        self.buffer = [0 for x in range(self.N)]
        self.discard_counter = [0 for x in range(self.N)]
        self.tasks = self.create_tasks()
        observation = self.get_obs()
        return observation
    
    def is_terminated(self):
        if(sum(self.capacity) + sum(self.buffer) + sum(self.tasks) == 0):
            return True
        return False
    
    def update_buffer(self):
        # deal with discarded tasks
        for i, t in enumerate(self.discard_counter):
            if t == 0 and self.buffer[i] > 0:
                self.buffer[i] = 0
                self.reward -= 1000
            elif self.buffer[i] != 0:
                self.discard_counter[i] -= 1

        # move tasks to next position if possible
        if sum(self.buffer) != 0:
            while self.buffer[0] == 0:
                for i in range(len(self.buffer) - 1):
                    self.buffer[i] = self.buffer[i+1]
                    self.discard_counter[i] = self.discard_counter[i+1]
                self.buffer[-1] = 0
    
    def update_capacity(self, action):
        # fill capacity from buffer
        #while sum(self.buffer) > 0 and sum(self.capacity) < len(self.capacity) + 1:
        for i, buffer_value in enumerate(self.buffer):
            if buffer_value == 0:
                break
            if sum(self.capacity) + buffer_value > len(self.capacity):
                break
            for j, x in enumerate(self.capacity):
                if x == 0:
                    self.capacity[j] = buffer_value
                    self.discard_counter[i] = 0
                    self.buffer[i] = 0

        self.update_buffer()

        # capacity empty
        if sum(self.capacity) < 1:
            return
        # move tasks to next position if possible
        while self.capacity[0] < 1:
            for i in range(len(self.capacity)-1):
                self.capacity[i] = self.capacity[i+1]
            self.capacity[-1] = 0
        if action == 1: # execute
            self.capacity[0] -= 2
        else: # offload to EC2
            self.capacity[0] = 2

    def add_task(self):
        # if enough capacity add task to LR
        if sum(self.capacity) + self.tasks[self.step_cnt // self.schedule_time] < len(self.capacity) + 1:
            for i in range(len(self.capacity)):
                if self.capacity[i] == 0:
                    self.capacity[i] = self.tasks[self.step_cnt // self.schedule_time]
                    return
        else:
            for i in range(len(self.buffer)):
                if(self.buffer[i] == 0):
                    self.buffer[i] = self.tasks[self.step_cnt // self.schedule_time]
                    self.discard_counter[i] = self.schedule_time
                    return
    
    def step(self, action):
        '''
        in theory I should secure that tasks that are already offloaded are not offloaded again
        however the agent will (should) learn this.
        '''
        self.reward -= 1
        self.update_capacity(action)
        if self.step_cnt % self.schedule_time == 0 and self.step_cnt // self.schedule_time < len(self.tasks):
            self.add_task()
        self.step_cnt += 1
        return self.get_obs(), self.reward, self.is_terminated(), {} #, False
    
    def close(self):
        # close files or windows opened if there are any
        # not required here
        pass


class Agent():
    def __init__(self, env: Env):
        self.env = env
        self.epsilon = 0.7
        self.learning_rate = 0.1
        num_states = 200*11*5 + 30*12
        self.Q_table = np.zeros((num_states, 2))

    def obs_to_state(self):
        #maps obs to int value, because i am unable to think in 6 dimensions
        obs = self.env.get_obs()
        arr1 = np.zeros((200, 11, 5)) # array representing buffer and discard_counter
        for i in range(len(obs['buffer'])):
            dc = obs['discard_counter'][i]
            val = obs['buffer'][i]
            arr1[i, val, dc] = 1
        arr1 = list(arr1.flatten())
        arr2 = np.zeros((30, 12))   # capacity array
        for i, v in enumerate(obs['capacity']):
            arr2[i, v] = 1
        arr2 = list(arr2.flatten())
        return arr1 + arr2

    def get_action(self):
        if random.random() < self.epsilon:
            # exploit
            state = self.obs_to_state()
            return np.argmax(self.Q_table[state]) + 1
        else:
            # explore
            return random.randint(1,2)
    


if __name__ == "__main__":

    gym.register(
        id='Env-v0',  # Unique ID for your environment
        entry_point=__name__ + ':Env',  # Entry point to your custom environment class
    )

    # skipped step: https://www.gymlibrary.dev/content/environment_creation/#creating-a-package

    env = gym.make('Env-v0')
    agent = Agent(env)
    obs = env.reset()
    test = agent.obs_to_state()
    print(test)
```
````